# .Find doesn't work in Macro, does when doing manually

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find a regex string, `<XE "i@>`, in a Word document.

Background: I'm building an index, and automatically picking up paragraphs to add via another macro.  There are some entries that start "i. Automobile - means a car", or "ii. Super - means really good".  I want to remove the numbering part from the Index entry, so thought a way to do so would be to look for the `{XE "i. Automobile ...}` part and just remove the `i.` using RegEx.

When I search manually for my string, it works fine and picks up the matches.  However, my macro doesn't work.  When stepping through, then I get to `While .Execute`, the *next* step just goes to `Wend` then `End With`. It **does** ask if I want to search from the beginning, so the `.Find` is working somewhat, but why isn't it finding any matches?

Thanks so much for any advice!

```
Sub Hide_Roman_Numerals_from_Index()
Dim defText As String
Dim regExSearch As String
Dim oRng As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range

If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = False Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = True
End If

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
'Call ClearFindAndReplaceParameters(oRng)
regExSearch = "<XE ""i@>"
oRng.Find.ClearFormatting
With oRng.Find
        .Text = regExSearch
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    While .Execute
        Set rng = oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range
        rng.Select
    Wend
End With

If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = True Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = False
End If
'Call ClearFindAndReplaceParameters(oRng)
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, your code works for me in my test environment, except that it loops the first found instance continually. As discussed in an earlier question you need to reset the Range object used for Find. What it does not do, however, is delete the dot-space following the roman numeral?

Comment: I could not understand what you want to do after finding? You want to replace every instance of `<XE "i@>` or just execute find so that you can assign the paragraph that contain `<XE "i@>` as range?

Answer (score 1):

I think this approach will suit you if I got your problem right.

```
'BruceWayne
Sub Colorgreenfromw()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim oPar As Paragraph
Dim oRng As Word.Range
For Each oPar In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    Set oRng = oPar.Range
    With oRng
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Color = wdColorGreen
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "<XE ""i@>"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
        End With
            If .Find.Found Then
                Set oRng = oPar.Range
                    oRng.Font.Color = wdColorGreen
                Set oRng = Nothing
            End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @BruceWayne: Green is my favorite color!

Comment: @BruceWayne: can you tell me is this what you wanted?

Comment: Hey Rahul, sorry for the delay.  It's close, but not quite.  I got pretty in the weeds when working through this, and confused myself.  I'm going to take a step back, and see what I need to do.  However, this is a help because I could use the `.Paragraphs` to loop through.  Thanks for your help mate!